# Selecting incorrect records

Tags: asp.net, sql

In following query, what is happening is that, the 3rd join is not being done. we are getting pharmacy match and then the display is showing patients in other facilities who share the same pharmacy, can you see why this would be happening?

```
Insert Into @tblNDC
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_KEY DESC) AS RN,* 
From
(
 Select distinct A.PHARMACYNPI, 
 f.FACILITY_NAME, 
 ID_KEY, 
 [BATCH] AS column1, 
 [IMPORTDATE], 
 [DATEBILLED], 
 [RX], 
 [DATEDISPENSED], 
 [DAYSUPPLY], 
 [PAYTYPE], 
 A.[NPI], 
 [PHYSICIAN], 
 [COST], 
 [QUANTITY], 
 [MEDICATION], 
 A.[NDC], 
 f.FACILITY_ID 
 FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]   
 --Left Outer Join PBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI
 Left Outer Join PBM.PHARMACY_NPI pn on A.PHARMACYNPI = pn.NPI
 Inner join PBM.PHARMACY_FACILITY pp on pn.PHARMACY_ID = pp.PHARMACY_ID
 Inner Join PBM.FACILITY f on pp.FACILITY_ID = f.FACILITY_ID
 Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5)
 AND [TIER] <> 'T1'
 AND f.FACILITY_ID IN 
 (
  select FacilityID from @tblFacility
 )
 AND f.FACILITY_ID IN 
 (
  SELECT * FROM [PBM].[Split1] (@selectedFacility)
 )
```

### --- it seems 3rd condition not being done  ----------------------------------

Comment: which 3rd join? `pbm.pharmacy_npi`, or `pbm.pharmacy_facility`?

Comment: inner Join PBM.FACILITY f on pp.FACILITY_ID = f.FACILITY_ID because its showing patients from diff facilities but they share same pharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to see for sure without knowing the data, but my first thoughts are that the Left Outer joins will be giving you joinage you might not want.

Go through each join and remove it until you start to get dodgy records back, if it is the 3rd one when it suddenly goes strange, then i suspect you have multiple IDs for a facility.

Comment: on this one, Left Outer Join PBM.PHARMACY_NPI pn on A.PHARMACYNPI = pn.NPI  we can have 2 different pharmacies that share that same id.